# validation format - Reges expression

Tags: regex, vb.net

I believe my validation is correct however it is not working.

My regular expression pattern is

```
ValidationExpression= "(I|II|III|IV)[DEF]?"
```

Basically, the user should put any of the first options then with optional D, E or F

Valid text Example: IIIC
Thank you

Comment: No. It is basically I or II or III or IV with optional letter DEF. that's the only allowed patterns the above question is different. Allowed Examples. ID, IE, IF, IID, IIE, IIF, IIID, IIIE, IIIF, IVD, IVE, IVF

Comment: [Look here, `^(I|II|III|IV)[DEF]?$` does exactly what you need.](https://regex101.com/r/1V5Gcp/1) Just add `^` and `$`.

Comment: Wiktor, your right. Many Thanks!

Comment: I just don't understand why some people vote down others questions! I mean what you gonna gain out of it?! if things are obvious to you perhaps you could be more considerate and realise we are all in different levels, I did not see the above question as duplicate, I mean seriously if i would find a useful answer to my question why bother asking in first place, the reason I published a question shows I didnt find answer. and also clearly from my question you can see I was nearly there which means I worked hard and read about it to be that close!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know much about regex, but I did a quick bit of googling and came up with this:

https://regex101.com/r/KYpVbk/1

It explains how it works at the side :)

Comment: I voted your answer up coz the tool you've provided is very useful! Thank you :)

Comment: @Sam no problem, If this is the correct answer you can select it as the correct answer to your question :)